# Google calendar api- get default event notifications settings

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am trying to fetch calendar event details using google web api, and in the response I see:

```
"reminders":{"useDefault":true}
```

Is there a way to somehow see what is the actual default value for reminders? I tried querying the calendar settings but I can't see anything related to reminders. I can't find anything related in the api reference also.
Am I missing something or is it just not possible to know the default reminders time via google api??

Comment: Try querying the Calendar GET API. Try something like - https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{calendarId} where calendarId will be the year of the calendar.
Ensure you have the permissions as well.
Thank you

Comment: Have you tried using the [[calendar.events.list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list%5D)]? It will show you the default reminders value that you set.

Comment: @Serenity i tried, but if i don't have a custom notification for the event, all i see is "useDefault: true" without an actual value

Comment: @niryo Do you have an event notification set for the calendar ID that you are doing the query? To check go to Google Calendar - "Settings" - "Settings for my calendars" - click the calendar name - find "Event notifications".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to get the calendar default reminder value:**

Under Calendar API events [list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list) or `Calendarlist` [get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/calendarList/get). In the requested parameters, under calendarID enter [primary](https://imgur.com/a/Yar6Pys) if you will use the primary calendar. If you will use the secondary calendars that you have, enter the full calendarID.

Next, click 'Execute'.  Then if the response is 200 it should show you the default reminders value if you have set an event notification for that calendar.

[image]

Since the default reminder value is already declared in the first part like what is shown above, for the events under that calendar that there's no modification in reminders it will only show:

`"reminders":{"useDefault":true}`

That means it is using the default value you set for that calendar's reminder. It will only specify a specific value if there's changes in the reminder for an event.

Example:

[image]

**Reference:**

- [Reminder](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/concepts/reminders)

Comment: Feel free to ask if you have any questions with respect to the answer posted above.

Comment: thanks! I somehow missed the calendarList api:)